# MongoDB aggregate group by project and then sum of weeks hours

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this entry structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56de0178cf7970ac2a86fb23"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-07T16:32:24.681-06:00"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-03-07T16:32:24.681-06:00"),
    "yearTask" : 2016,
    "startWeek" : 10,
    "task" : "31231321",
    "hours" : 312,
    "project" : [ 
        {
            "Project" : "1000G",
            "_id" : "565f193cea6493ce0acc9730"
        }
    ],
    "plannedWeeks" : [ 
        {
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "hours" : 3,
            "weekNumber" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "hours" : 3,
            "weekNumber" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "hours" : 3,
            "weekNumber" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "hours" : 3,
            "weekNumber" : 13
        }, 
        {
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "hours" : 3,
            "weekNumber" : 14
        }
    ],
}
```

So imagine that I have other entries and I need the total sum of hours for each week (weekNumber)  and also I need to have this information group by project (in this case the name of the project is "Project"). The number of weeks are variable. **The project field is an array, but only contains one project.**.

The output would look like this :

```
{
   _id : {
           "name" : "1000G",
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "weeks" : [ 
                    {
                        "yearTask" : 2016,
                        "hours" : 34, <--Total sum for this project and week
                        "weekNumber" : 10
                    }

                 .... etc.

             ]

        },
   _id : {
           "name" : "Project2",
            "yearTask" : 2016,
            "weeks" : [ 
                    {
                        "yearTask" : 2016,
                        "hours" : 584,<--Total sum for this project and week
                        "weekNumber" : 10
                    }

                 .... etc.

             ]

        } 

}
```

My current query only groups the planned weeks by project:

```
db.tasks.aggregate(
   [
        { "$unwind": "$project" },
        {$group : {
           _id : { 
               name : "$project.Project", 
               yearTask : "$yearTask",  
               weeks : "$plannedWeeks",

            },
            /*"matches" : { "$sum" : "$plannedWeeks.hours" },*/
        }},
        { $match : { "_id.yearTask": { $eq: 2016 } } },

   ]
)
```

I tried to use `{ "$unwind": "$plannedWeeks" }`, but I don't know how to sum the total of every week and then group them by project

**Edited - My solution was :**

```
   [
    { "$match" : { "yearTask": 2016 } },
    { "$unwind": "$project" },
    { "$unwind": "$plannedWeeks" },
    /*{ "$match" : { "yearTask": 2016 } },*/
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$project.Project",
                /*"yearTask": "$plannedWeeks.yearTask",*/
                "weekYear": "$plannedWeeks.yearTask",
                "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
            },
            "weeks": {
                "$push": {
                    "yearTask": "$plannedWeeks.yearTask",                   
                    "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
                }
            },
            "hours": { "$sum": "$plannedWeeks.hours" },            
        }
    },
    { $sort : { "_id.weekYear" : 1,"_id.weekNumber" : 1, } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            /*"yearTask": "$_id.yearTask",*/
        },
        "weeks": {
            "$push": {
                 "yearTask": "$_id.weekYear",
                 "hours": "$hours",
                 "weekNumber": "$_id.weekNumber"
            }
        }
    }},


]
```

Comment: `project` is an array, so does a document imply that all the projects in a document map against the same `planned weeks`?

Comment: The project field is an array but only contains one project (it contains the project info).  You can ignore that and imagine that it's something like this:
...
project_name : 'Project X',
plannedWeeks: [ ....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages to first total up by "week" and then [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the results into the rolled-up key for each stage.

Ideally with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) from MongoDB 3.2:

```js
db.tasks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$plannedWeeks" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$project.Project", 0 ] },
            "yearTask": "$yearTask",
            "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
        },
        "hours": { "$sum": "$plannedWeeks.hours" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "yearTask": "$_id.yearTask",
        },
        "weeks": {
            "$push": {
                 "yearTask": "$_id.yearTask",
                 "hours": "$hours",
                 "weekNumber": "$_id.weekNumber"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

And of course since `"project"` is an array of only one item, then there is no problem with using `$unwind` there as well in earlier versions

```js
db.tasks.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$plannedWeeks" },
    { "$unwind": "$project" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$project.Project",
            "yearTask": "$yearTask",
            "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
        },
        "hours": { "$sum": "$plannedWeeks.hours" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$_id.name",
            "yearTask": "$_id.yearTask",
        },
        "weeks": {
            "$push": {
                 "yearTask": "$_id.yearTask",
                 "hours": "$hours",
                 "weekNumber": "$_id.weekNumber"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

At any rate, it's two `$group` stages where the first does the sum and the next creates the array.

It's probably a good idea to reconsider the usage of an array for `"project"` if it's only ever going to contain one element. Multiple arrays in documents can cause problems if you expect some sort of correlation between the data contained, and that is generally better expressed in a single array instead, or as just a base property, even nested.

As always, `$match` first in aggregation pipelines if you actually intend to filter document content by conditions in results.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know that. The output of this query is what I wanted, but for some reason the sum of hours is no correct. So I made adjustments to the query. I combined your answer and @chridam 's answer too. I would like to accept both answers but only one can be chosen, so I will choose this one. Thanks.

Comment: @EdgarMoreno I didn't really see it was clear in your question that you only wanted the array entries that matched the "yearTask" field there. Even your original attempt only looks at the "yearTask" that is "outside" of the array, and therefore would be the initial `$match` as commented ( but it wansn't a clear requirement and therefore just a mention ). Note that if the "yearTask" within the array is **always** the same as in the document, then processing `$match` after `$unwind` would not be required. Which was again the point being made.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it. it was my bad. But your answer solved my question about how to group the hours by project. Thanks. And you are correct about the $match after $unwind.

Comment: @EdgarMoreno Well that is the point, as we can only really answer the question you actually ask. At least you should have learned something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running the following aggregation pipeline to get the correct result

```
pipeline = [
    { "$match" : { "plannedWeeks.yearTask": 2016 } },
    { "$unwind": "$project" },
    { "$unwind": "$plannedWeeks" },
    { "$match" : { "plannedWeeks.yearTask": 2016 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$project.Project",
                "yearTask": "$plannedWeeks.yearTask",
                "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
            },
            "weeks": {
                "$push": {
                    "yearTask": "$plannedWeeks.yearTask",                   
                    "weekNumber": "$plannedWeeks.weekNumber"
                }
            },
            "totalHours": { "$sum": "$plannedWeeks.hours" },            
        }
    }
]
db.tasks.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but the output is kind of different. The sum of hours is correct for each week and project. Is there a way to group the 'totalHours' (and weekNumber) by project? 
The current result is an array of all weeks, but I would be nice if it can be an array of projects.